# Electrodes for electroporation of bacterial cells

Tags: electrophysiology

Wikipedia says

> ["The process {electroporation} requires direct contact between the electrodes and the suspension."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroporation)

However I've read the process is an effect of the field strength alone, and ideally no current passes at all, due to its heating and other unwanted effects. Why can there not then be a resistive layer between the electrodes and sample to stop any current flowing?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure that this is the right site to answer this question - you might be better migrating to electrical engineering or  physics for a complete answer. I suspect that if it worked without direct current, then it would be done that way - perhaps you have a new idea and you can test it and potentially get a patent.